# Is there a way to run a -.jar file (created with javaFx) without displaying anything(GUI, progressbar, ...)?

Tags: java

I wrote a java file including javaFX. Now, I want to run this file, like
java -jar example.jar
But I'd like to suppress the graphical output. 
Is there any possible, like a flag or anything else, to do this?
My program normally shows a progressbar and after that a video of the simulation.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Read an argument, or a system property, or whatever you want in your main method, and act accordingly: either show the UI, or don't.

Comment: You want to start a GUI application... without the GUI? Seems pointless. Could you elaborate your use case?

Comment: Sounds like a **XY problem**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To elaborate on *JB Nizet*'s comment.
JAR files have manifests. In order to run your JAR using the command `java -jar example.jar`, the manifest must have a `Main-Class` entry. And your *main class* must have a `main()` method.

So launch your app like so...

```
java -jar example.jar NO_GUI
```

And in your `main()` method, write something like the following...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length > 0  &&  "NO_GUI".equals(args[0]) {
        // Don't show GUI
    }
    else {
        // Show the GUI.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could call `hide()` on the scene so the window dissapears.

Answer (score 2):

There is not really a way to force this.

Instead, implement it as feature. Create a command line argument `nogui` and react to it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean useGui = true;
    if (args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("nogui")) {
        doNotUseGui = false;
    }

    // Create your program and give it the flag
    Program prog = new Program(useGui);
    ...
}
```

Note that theoretically it would be possible to *hack* your application and remove any such calls, or to suppress the calls on a native level. But I guess that is not really the route you want to go.